# How to calculate discounts on in-app products

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-billing

Recently I have implemented in-app purchases (subscriptions, more specifically) in my
**Android** app.

My initial idea was to have a month, a quarterly, and a yearly subscription, and make it clear to the user how much discount (compared to the monthly) they would get by signing either the quarterly or the yearly.

The problem is that **Google's Billing API** doesn't provide you with the actual price for the products, just with an already localized and formatted price string.

I found out the hard way that converting that string to a price and doing calculations on top of it isn't failproof.

So my question here is: have any of you managed to do discount calculations on top of in-app product prices?

Thanks in advance.